# Implement verification user exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

I would like to check if the user has already filled in the registration form:

Here is my code for the connectionState:

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {

//  final Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          User user = snapshot.data;
          if (user == null) {
            return SignInPage();
          } else {
//            _geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
            MatchEngine.instance.initialise(user.uid);
            return Chat();
          }
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: MyAppsCircularProgressIndicator(title: "MyApp",),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this code works fine for connectionstate.

I would like to add in the first code:

```
if (not signed in) {
  show sign in page
} else {
  if (not registered)
    show register page
  else 
    show home page
}
```

or

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: auth.authStateChanges()
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    // check connectionState too
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: database.userData() // this is a stream you create that reads from `userData/$uid` or similar
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomePage()
          } else {
            return RegisterPage()
          }
        }
      )
    } else {
      return SignInPage()
    }
  }
)
```

I would like to add the last code to the previous one to have my connectionstate + my redirection to RegisterPage.

I tried everything but to no avail ... could someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the provider package and then create a seperate file which has the following code. I personally use this and it works well.

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    if (user == null) {
      return SignIn();
    } else {
      return Dashboard();
    }
  }
}
```

and in your main.dart file where you are building the material app. Put the wrapper (or whatever you name it) widget instead such as the following.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return ErrorPage();
        }

        // Show Application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamProvider<Help4YouUser>.value(
            value: AuthService().user,
            child: MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: Wrapper(),
            ),
          );
        }

        // Initialization
        return LoadingWidget();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Any clarification needed please comment

Comment: Hello, I already use the provider, and my redirection method works well, I do not see in your code the redirection to the register pages. register pages is your error pages?   I prefer not to load my main and put the code in my landing page

Comment: @rpz I am not really sure if I understand you correctly. Is the register page a custom page created inside the app and are you using google sign in in your app. Please let me know those 2 queries and I may be able to further help you.

Comment: I use the google connection, and I would like that once the user authenticates with google, if the user is new he goes to the register page, if he is not new he goes to the home.

And I would like to keep my existing code (the first) which allows to redirect an opening of the application either on the home or on the signinpage

you understand? thanks

Comment: i woold like implement second code in first code. if the connection is active, go home, if it is not active, go to the connection, and after being authenticated with google if a new registration page, if already existing, go home.

Comment: @rpz If you are using google sign in then what I suggest you to do is in your authentication code where you will be authenticating what you can do is if user authentication is successful then create a cloud firestore document for the user. after you have implemented that you can add a check inside the if user uid and document id don't match then go to your register page else if user uid and document id match then go to your home page and I think this should solve the problem. If you want to help in implementing this idea I can help you out with it.